# How to concatenate labels in Prometheus relabel config

Tags: prometheus

I have a fleet of EC2 instances and want to relabel their prometheus names to be like: `${__meta_ec2_tag_Name}:${__meta_ec2_private_ip}` so my relabeled name will look like `portal-service:10.0.19.98`.

I'm understand how to relabel a single label using regex, but don't know how to use a several source labels.

My current config relabel instance name to private ip, but I want to add something else (and perhaps more than one keys) to it:

```
  relabel_configs:
    - source_labels: ['__meta_ec2_private_ip']
      target_label: 'instance'
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All source labels are concatenated by semicolon by default, but it can be changed:

```
source_labels: ['__meta_ec2_tag_Name', '__meta_ec2_private_ip']
separator: ':'
target_label: instance
```